# Outlook 2016 Quick Print Doesn't Work with PDFs

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, microsoft-office

I have two endusers that are now unable to Quick Print PDFs from Outlook 2016.  They can Quick Print Excel, and such but not PDF.  There seems to be nothing that has changed recently, since they are standard users they would not be able to change the system in any significant way.

I tried updating Acrobat Reader to the latest version, Outlook is from the 365 subscription and seems to be up-to-date as well.

While the feature isn't mission critical, the two employees would like to have that feature working again and I am at a loss as nothing seems to make a difference.

Comment: I have almost the exact same issue. On my users, it's all kind of attachments, that it doesn't work on. Or, it does work, but only if you open the mails first. It seems like it doesn't know where the file(s) are, when you do a "quick print" from view-menu. It's not able to create a temp-file, like when you go into the mail (and print). Hopefully you have found a solution for this, and want to share it :) otherwise, i hope somebody else have a solution for this. :) Because the only solution i have, is a workaround. Thanks, Brady

Comment: This needs converted to a **comment** by a mod.

Comment: Is there a disabled Adobe COM add-in perhaps?